# Connecting Pentaho Data Integration to a Firebird SQL database

Tags: driver, pentaho, firebird, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to establish an input table in a pentaho transformation but when I try to connect to the database, the following error appears:

> Driver class 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Firebird SQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
> javax/resource/ResourceException

I have already tried all firebird drivers available at https://firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/ and copied the jar files into `C:\Program Files\data-integration\lib`, but the error shown above keeps showing up....

All questions I found are about old version of Firebird like 2.1

Comment: Please provide the full exception message, and specify which Jaybird version you're trying to use. The error suggest that maybe you're using Jaybird 4 or earlier, and did not include the connector-api-1.5.jar in the classpath. Either switch to Jaybird 5, or make sure to either use jaybird-full.jar instead of jaybird.jar, or add connector-api-1.5.jar. However, without more information, that is just guessing.